# Обновление цен на Шопифай (Shopify)

Tags: csv, shopify

Заказчик прислал прайс и попросил обновить цены на группу товаров. Я выгрузил товары в csv-файл, в нем для каждого товара указан идентификатор (handle). Но проблема в том что у вариативных товаров они совпадают. Получается что есть товары с одинаковым идентификатором. Я протестировал с одним вариативным товаром и в итоге количество вариантов у него уменьшилось. Как можно обновить цену товаров не меняя при этом других данных?

Вот что пишет сам Шопифай:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и еще:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а это файл который у меня получился:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]